# WPF DataGrid populating the cells as they become visible

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have always been using a Syncfusion virtual grid which works on the basis of an override on that grid that is fired for each cell that is visible!  It provides me with information on the row and column and some cell object that lets me set the value of that cell, its formatting, colours etc.

This allowed for very fast scrolling on **very** large datasets, since I simply have to 'read out' the value like dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[1000000]["LastName"].ToString()

Is there anything similar exposed by the WPF DataGrid?

EDIT
I need to make myself clearer - I know about virtualization and that it switches itself off when you do grouping etc.  Having run a test with grouping enabled over a dataset of 20,000
rows made my grid choke on itself.
Therefore my previous question stands on its own!
Is there any way the grid allows me to fill in the text and do some formatting through some override or callback?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The DataGrid uses virtualization by default. This works by either creating and deleting cells on the fly or by recycling the visible cells and repopulating them with the current row's data. This can be turned off as well as tweaked by playing with the 'VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode' property and is forced off in many situations (grouping is a good example). This virtualization can be a godsend and a curse. If you have a simple set of requirements, then it makes it dead easy to get good performance. If on the other hand you are doing complex runtime binding, including triggers and custom columns, then it becomes a bit of a nightmare.

a couple of important reads:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716879.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but it is not what I meant - I have edited my question above.  I believe I know that the answer will be - No, there isn't - which will be disappointing but I will then just have to accept the fact that DataGrids with lots of data are inherently slow - EVEN with (default) virtualisation enabled!

Comment: @Marcel, I think you have asked the wrong question then, because 'reading out the value of x[100000].name.tostring()' is exactly what the recycled virtualization is doing. If you require virtualization of grouped data, then the DataGrid will not likely help you. If on the other hand it is the speed of accessing x[100000] itself, than this could be a Data virtualization issue. Here's an interesting PDF of the subject: http://bea.stollnitz.com/files/52/DataVirtualization.pdf

Comment: thanks for that again ach - there is still a lag when I drag the vertical scrollbar when I have > 25,000 rows in a virtualised DataGrid. Now much but my boss is annoyed that it doesn't match the speed of Excel that can cope with over a million rows and scrolls perfectly!

Comment: Have you set the Virtualization mode to Recycle? It is much faster than the standard virtualization. Also There is another setting called 'ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled' which would also increase apparent performance by only updating the visible cells when scrolling has finished.